# RegEx in C# to get all SPAN tags with a specific Class name

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am required to fetch all SPAN tags with CLASS CLASSIFY. In one of the case, the RegEx which I am using is skipping the First SPAN tag.

**RegEx**

```
<span [^>]*class=\"classify\"(.*?)</span>
```

**C# Code**

```
Regex.Matches(content, "<span [^>]*class=\"classify\"(.*?)</span>", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

**Content:**

```
<span categoryid="110" categorytext="(Sup ed (Inl))" class="classify" classifyid="3395349" quoteid="" quotetext="" selectedclassify="true" style="font-weight: bold; background-color: #ffa500">
<u>Objective/reason for interaction</u>
<br />  wtwt
<br />  &nbsp;
<br />  <u>Summary</u><br />  As  -16/08/15</span>
<br />  &nbsp;
<br />  
<u>Actions</u>
<br />  N
<br />  &nbsp;
<br />  
<u>Outcomes/reportables</u>
<br />  
<span categorytext="(Nofrf of J Ced)" class="classify" quoteid="" quotetext="" selectedclassify="false" style="categoryid=&quot;13416&quot;">1 full </span>
<br />  A Mag
<br />  &nbsp;
<br />  
<u>K</u>
<br />  As ab
<br />
```

**Link to .Net RegEx tester:**

[Sample](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Cspan%20%5B%5E%3E%5D*class%3D%5C%22classify%5C%22%28.*%3F%29%3C%2Fspan%3E&i=%3Cspan%20categoryid%3D%22110%22%20categorytext%3D%22%28Sup%20ed%20%28Inl%29%29%22%20class%3D%22classify%22%20classifyid%3D%223395349%22%20quoteid%3D%22%22%20quotetext%3D%22%22%20selectedclassify%3D%22true%22%20style%3D%22font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%20background-color%3A%20%23ffa500%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cu%3EObjective%2Freason%20for%20interaction%3C%2Fu%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20wtwt%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%26nbsp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%3Cu%3ESummary%3C%2Fu%3E%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20As%20%20-16%2F08%2F15%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%26nbsp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cu%3EActions%3C%2Fu%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20N%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%26nbsp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cu%3EOutcomes%2Freportables%3C%2Fu%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20categorytext%3D%22%28Nofrf%20of%20J%20Ced%29%22%20class%3D%22classify%22%20quoteid%3D%22%22%20quotetext%3D%22%22%20selectedclassify%3D%22false%22%20style%3D%22categoryid%3D%26quot%3B13416%26quot%3B%22%3E1%20full%20%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20A%20Mag%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%26nbsp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cu%3EK%3C%2Fu%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20As%20ab%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20&o=m)

Please advice, what I am missing in the RegEx.

Comment: HTML **is not** a regular language. You can't use a regular language parser (i.e. RegEx) to parse it. You need to use something designed to do so, like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Have a read of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/259769

Comment: The parser is already in place, so I cannot change the whole code to make use of the HTML Agility Pack now.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you have some good unit tests associated with this code and that you are in control of the HTML that you are parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the dot doesn't match new lines by default. You can use [\s\S] instead:

```
<span [^>]*class=\"classify\"([\s\S]*?)</span>
```

Or you can use your original pattern and set the [Singleline option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) in RegexOptions.

[Regex Tester link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Cspan%20%5B%5E%3E%5D*class%3D%5C%22classify%5C%22%28%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%3F%29%3C%2Fspan%3E&i=%3Cspan%20categoryid%3D%22110%22%20categorytext%3D%22%28Sup%20ed%20%28Inl%29%29%22%20class%3D%22classify%22%20classifyid%3D%223395349%22%20quoteid%3D%22%22%20quotetext%3D%22%22%20selectedclassify%3D%22true%22%20style%3D%22font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%20background-color%3A%20%23ffa500%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cu%3EObjective%2Freason%20for%20interaction%3C%2Fu%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20wtwt%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%26nbsp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%3Cu%3ESummary%3C%2Fu%3E%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20As%20%20-16%2F08%2F15%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%26nbsp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cu%3EActions%3C%2Fu%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20N%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%26nbsp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cu%3EOutcomes%2Freportables%3C%2Fu%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20categorytext%3D%22%28Nofrf%20of%20J%20Ced%29%22%20class%3D%22classify%22%20quoteid%3D%22%22%20quotetext%3D%22%22%20selectedclassify%3D%22false%22%20style%3D%22categoryid%3D%26quot%3B13416%26quot%3B%22%3E1%20full%20%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20A%20Mag%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%26nbsp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cu%3EK%3C%2Fu%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20As%20ab%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%20%20&o=m)

Comment: Perfect, this work. One quick question(as my knowledge is very limited here), what is the best solution i.e. to make use of [\s\S] or Singleline option?

Comment: I'm not sure but I would guess they're equivalent. The docs for Singleline say it "changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n)." [\s\S] finds a whitespace character or not whitespace character, so it is doing essentially the same thing.

Comment: Although [\s\S] might be more portable to other languages.

Comment: Alright, thanks again. I'll make use of Singleline here.